# Is there a way to redirect to a specific page using Tank_auth in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, authentication, tankauth

I'm wondering if there's a way to redirect to a specific page (like adminpanel_view) in Tank_auth.
I looked at the Auth.php controller but could not figure out how to redirect, if it's even possible..

I tried this:

(Auth.php)

```
public function login() //login functie
{
    $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'auth/login' ,'title' => 'Login');         
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {                                 // logged in
        redirect('members/cpanel');
    } elseif ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in(FALSE)) {                      // logged in, not activated
        redirect('/auth/send_again/');

    } else {
        $data['login_by_username'] = ($this->config->item('login_by_username', 'tank_auth') AND
                $this->config->item('use_username', 'tank_auth'));
        $data['login_by_email'] = $this->config->item('login_by_email', 'tank_auth');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember me', 'integer');

        // Get login for counting attempts to login
        if ($this->config->item('login_count_attempts', 'tank_auth') AND
                ($login = $this->input->post('login'))) {
            $login = $this->security->xss_clean($login);
        } else {
            $login = '';
        }

        $data['use_recaptcha'] = $this->config->item('use_recaptcha', 'tank_auth');
        if ($this->tank_auth->is_max_login_attempts_exceeded($login)) {
            if ($data['use_recaptcha'])
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field', 'Confirmation Code', 'trim|xss_clean|required|callback__check_recaptcha');
            else
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Confirmation Code', 'trim|xss_clean|required|callback__check_captcha');
        }
        $data['errors'] = array();

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {                                // validation ok
            if ($this->tank_auth->login(
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
                    $data['login_by_username'],
                    $data['login_by_email'])) {                             // success
                redirect('');

            } else {
                $errors = $this->tank_auth->get_error_message();
                if (isset($errors['banned'])) {                             // banned user
                    $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_banned').' '.$errors['banned']);

                } elseif (isset($errors['not_activated'])) {                // not activated user
                    redirect('/auth/send_again/');

                } else {                                                    // fail
                    foreach ($errors as $k => $v)   $data['errors'][$k] = $this->lang->line($v);
                }
            }
        }
        $data['show_captcha'] = FALSE;
        if ($this->tank_auth->is_max_login_attempts_exceeded($login)) {
            $data['show_captcha'] = TRUE;
            if ($data['use_recaptcha']) {
                $data['recaptcha_html'] = $this->_create_recaptcha();
            } else {
                $data['captcha_html'] = $this->_create_captcha();
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('auth/login_form', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have loaded url_helper before using function `base_url`, `site_url` or `redirect`. and your code could not run, because you missed a brace. it should be

```
public function login() //login functie
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> site_url('auth/login') ,'title' => 'Login');         
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {      // logged in
        redirect('members/cpanel');
    }
}
```

Comment: actually that's not the whole code. I did not forgot to add an brace `{` I already loaded the url_helper. This is exactly the same as what I've tried.

Comment: so, what happend when you redirect?

Comment: Nothing. It still redirects to the homepage, as default.

Comment: why should there be another redirect? I would have posted that... I will post my whole function.

Comment: I mean `members/cpanel` not the `login` function

Comment: did you have a `MY_Controller` ?

Comment: No I don't have a MY_Controller.

Comment: I noticed that there is a `redirect` in `if ($this->form_validation->run()) ` block. are you sure `$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()` returns TRUE in your code?

Comment: I totally missed the second redirect. This one works. thanks for pointing me to it.